# Unable to install latte-dock in Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, kde

So I uninstalled Latte a few days ago because it was giving some problems, but now I can't install it anymore. When I run:

```
sudo apt install latte-dock
```

I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package latte-dock is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'latte-dock' has no installation candidate
```

However, I tried to look for latte using `apt search` and I can see it in the list. I also tried to install it using Discover, but when I click on the install button it doesn't do anything.

The `universe` repository is already enabled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) as this package is [located in *universe* pocket](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=latte-dock). Simply run `sudo add-apt-repository universe` and retry.

Comment: @N0rbert when I run that I get `'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.`

Comment: Then please run `sudo apt update`, check its output and it to the question (click [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1146178/edit) to do so).

Comment: @N0rbert I was able to fix the problem by adding the `main universe restricted multiverse` repository, using `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse"`

Comment: Then add this solution as self-answer to help other users :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so for some strange reason (any input on this would be helpful), I had to add the `main universe restricted multiverse` to my list of repository. You can do this by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse"
```

Then running `sudo apt update` and installing latte works fine.